# How to split a type into multiple columns in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, plperl

I have the following code to return multiple values from pl/python:

```
CREATE TYPE named_value AS (
  name   text,
  value  integer
);
CREATE or replace FUNCTION make_pair (name text, value integer)
  RETURNS named_value
AS $$
  return [ name, value ]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

select make_pair('egg', 4) as column;
```

The output is:

```
column
(egg,4)
```

What I want to do is to split the output into two separate columns. Like this:

```
column, column2
egg, 4
```

How do I do this? Googled for 1 hour got me nowhere. So I hope I will add some search keywords in the end:
multiple return values multiple results multiple columns unnest list unnest set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, the syntax for this is a bit wacky, requiring extra parentheses:

```
select (make_pair('egg', 4)).name
```

To get multiple components from the output while only invoking the function once, you can use a sub-select:

```
select (x.column).name, (x.column).value from (select make_pair('egg', 4) as column) x;
```

Comment: Your code works, but do I really need a sub-select for doing this? I was so close with make_pair('egg', 4).name, but that did not work.

Comment: You can say `select (make_pair('egg', 4)).name`, for example. If you want both components but only to execute the function once, I think you need the sub-select. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Not having to execute the function more than once is definitely an objective.

Comment: I have added my own answer with working code to avoid having to run the function twice and at the same time avoid a subquery. I will still accept your answer as you lead me to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM make_pair('egg', 4);
```

and some variants:

```
 SELECT name, value FROM make_pair('egg', 4) AS x;


 SELECT a, b FROM make_pair('egg', 4) AS x(a,b);
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, but I do not know how to use it in my case where I need to run the function on each row in a table. Performance is also very important for me.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I found was to use join:

```sql
create table tmp (a int, b int, c int);
insert into tmp (a,b,c) values (1,2,3), (3,4,5), (5,12,13);
create type ispyth3 as (is_it boolean, perimeter int);
create function check_it(int, int, int) returns ispyth3 as $$
    begin
        return ($1*$1 + $2*$2 = $3*$3, $1+$2+$3);
    end
$$ language plpgsql;
select * from tmp join check_it(a,b,c) on 1=1;
```

This returns:

```
 a | b  | c  | is_it | perimeter 
---+----+----+-------+-----------
 1 |  2 |  3 | f     |         6
 3 |  4 |  5 | t     |        12
 5 | 12 | 13 | t     |        30
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Another way to express the cross join is to use `JOIN CHECK_it(a,b,c) ON TRUE` or simply use `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working code to avoid having to run the function twice and at the same time avoid a subquery.

```
CREATE TYPE named_value AS (
  name   text,
  value  integer
);

CREATE or replace FUNCTION setcustomvariable(variablename text, variablevalue named_value)
  RETURNS named_value
AS $$
  GD[variablename] = variablevalue
  return variablevalue
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE or replace FUNCTION getcustomvariable(variablename text)
  RETURNS named_value
AS $$
  return GD[variablename]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

CREATE or replace FUNCTION make_pair (name text, value integer)
  RETURNS named_value
AS $$
  return [ name, value ]
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

select setcustomvariable('result', make_pair('egg', 4)), (getcustomvariable('result')).name, (getcustomvariable('result')).value
```